# MySQL - Group by multiple columns from same table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table similar to the following

```
sno | booking_id | room_type | gender | age | amount | days
1   | 2016JUL001 | AC        | Male   | 25  | 1000   | 15 
2   | 2016JUL001 | AC        | Male   | 42  | 1000   | 15 
3   | 2016JUL001 | AC        | Male   | 28  | 1000   | 15 
4   | 2016JUL010 | N AC      | Female | 45  | 1000   | 15 
5   | 2016JUL010 | N AC      | Female | 46  | 1000   | 15 
6   | 2016JUL005 | N AC      | Male   | 28  | 1000   | 15 
7   | 2016JUL005 | N AC      | Female | 35  | 1000   | 15 
8   | 2016JUL009 | AC        | Female | 26  | 1000   | 15 
9   | 2016JUL009 | AC        | Female | 25  | 1000   | 15
```

... so on

Expected output [If I want to get gender='Female']

```
sno | booking_id | room_type | gender | age | amount | days
4   | 2016JUL010 | N AC      | Female | 45  | 1000   | 15 
5   | 2016JUL010 | N AC      | Female | 46  | 1000   | 15
8   | 2016JUL009 | AC        | Female | 26  | 1000   | 15 
9   | 2016JUL009 | AC        | Female | 25  | 1000   | 15
```

Expected output [If I want to get gender='Male']

```
sno | booking_id | room_type | gender | age | amount | days
1   | 2016JUL001 | AC        | Male   | 25  | 1000   | 15 
2   | 2016JUL001 | AC        | Male   | 42  | 1000   | 15 
3   | 2016JUL001 | AC        | Male   | 28  | 1000   | 15
```

Expected output [If I want to get gender='Male' AND gender='Female']

```
sno | booking_id | room_type | gender | age | amount | days
6   | 2016JUL005 | N AC      | Male   | 28  | 1000   | 15 
7   | 2016JUL005 | N AC      | Female | 35  | 1000   | 15
```

**NOTE: I want 3 separate individual QUERIES to get the above outputs**

Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the question ?

Comment: Please read the complete post, I have mentioned the 3 expected outputs and the query to be modified @sagi

Comment: sathvik can you please expain your question

Comment: So you want 3 queries to create the 3 outputs you provided?

Comment: yeah, exactly @sagi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of tries, I am able to get the data I want

Query ['Female']

```
SELECT sno, bd.booking_id, bd.room_type, bd.gender, bd.age 
FROM customer_data bd 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT booking_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gender) AS g 
    FROM customer_data 
    WHERE gender!='' AND age>0 
    GROUP BY booking_id 
    HAVING COUNT(booking_id) > 1 
    ORDER BY booking_id ASC, gender DESC 
) cbd 
WHERE cbd.booking_id = bd.booking_id AND cbd.g = 'Female'
```

Query ['Male']

```
SELECT sno, bd.booking_id, bd.room_type, bd.gender, bd.age 
FROM customer_data bd 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT booking_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gender) AS g 
    FROM customer_data 
    WHERE gender!='' AND age>0 
    GROUP BY booking_id 
    HAVING COUNT(booking_id) > 1 
    ORDER BY booking_id ASC, gender DESC 
) cbd 
WHERE cbd.booking_id = bd.booking_id AND cbd.g ='Male'
```

Query ['Male and Female']

```
SELECT sno, bd.booking_id, bd.room_type, bd.gender, bd.age 
FROM customer_data bd 
INNER JOIN ( 
    SELECT booking_id, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gender ORDER BY gender DESC) AS g 
    FROM customer_data 
    WHERE gender!='' AND age>0 
    GROUP BY booking_id 
    HAVING COUNT(booking_id) > 1 
    ORDER BY booking_id ASC, gender DESC 
) cbd 
WHERE cbd.booking_id = bd.booking_id AND cbd.g = 'Male,Female'
```

Comment: Looks very inefficient . A) Replace `LIKE` with `=` when looking for perfect match. B) You can order by the `GROUP_CONCAT()` so it will always be the same order and you won't have to look both `Male,Female` and `Female,Male` . Look at my having clause, you can add it in the inner query , add to the having clause `HAVING MAX(gender) = 'female'` for only females , `HAVING MIN(gender) = 'man'` for mens. and `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT GENDER) = 2` for both.

Comment: Yeah I have already optimized in my code @sagi. Thank you, I have answered because some other will get some idea from this. Anyways, I will also edit here.

Comment: I think `HAVING MAX(gender) = 'female'` this will not work in some cases

Comment: We are talking about your scenario , only `man,female` available. So if `MAX` returns female and not male(since male is larger than female on ASCI table) that it must be the only option. Same goes for man.

Answer (score 3):

First query :

```
SELECT sno, booking_id, room_type, gender, age 
FROM customer_data 
WHERE booking_id IN ( SELECT booking_id FROM customer_data 
                      WHERE gender='female' AND age>0 and RIGHT(booking_id,1) <> '1' 
                      GROUP BY booking_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) 
ORDER BY booking_id ASC, age ASC
```

Second :

```
SELECT sno, booking_id, room_type, gender, age 
FROM customer_data 
WHERE booking_id IN ( SELECT booking_id FROM customer_data 
                      WHERE gender='male' AND age>0 
                      GROUP BY booking_id HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 ) 
ORDER BY booking_id ASC, age ASC
```

And third:

```
SELECT sno, booking_id, room_type, gender, age 
FROM customer_data 
WHERE booking_id IN ( SELECT booking_id FROM customer_data 
                      WHERE gender IN('male','female') AND age>0 
                      GROUP BY booking_id HAVING COUNT(distinct gender) = 2 ) 
ORDER BY booking_id ASC, age ASC
```

If in the first two you wanted only booking_id that has only 1 gender, add to the having clause :

```
AND COUNT(distinct gender) = 1
```

Comment: Booking ID's are not same as I mentioned.. It will change

Comment: Will change how? What's wrong? Are you expecting me to guess what you need?

Comment: Thanks. @Manishsharma

Comment: I mean there can be other bookings will have the number 1. you have mentioned `booking_id NOT LIKE '%1%'` in the query. The original format of booking id is YEARMONTHNUMBER [2016AUG0001]

Comment: Sorry for that, I mean to say is that will keep on increment and I have lots of rows and don't mention the booking id in such way.

Comment: I've changed the query to check if the last letter is not 1, it should work based on what you told me @SathvikCheela

Comment: Please don't mention `AND booking_id` condition

Comment: So delete it. I have no idea what do you want.

Comment: You are only considering 10 records I have mentioned but there are nearly 3000 records and more will be added every day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121527/discussion-between-sathvik-cheela-and-sagi).

Comment: So what? What do I care if more will be added? This is dynamic and should work on any amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

Your schema appears somewhat flawed. Nevertheless, here's something to think about...

```
SELECT booking_id
     , COUNT(DISTINCT gender) x 
  FROM customer_data 
 WHERE gender IN ('Male','Female') <-- not strictly necessary if there are only two genders.
 GROUP 
    BY booking_id;
```

Comment: By his query, I assume that there is also an empty string value for gender.

Comment: @sagi Yes, I think you're right - so it is necessary in this instance